# Matlab 2020a runs very slow on Mac OS Catalina

Tags: macos, matlab

My matlab 2020a runs very slow on Mac OS Catalina. When I move my mouse over the buttons in the menu bar it becomes very slow or even do not responding. When I opened an Applications, the Matlab becomes un-responding after few seconds. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: I would recommend you to contact the MathWorks Techincal support.

Comment: Catalina has fancier GUI flare that adds nothing. Try disabling those. (System Pref -> Accessibility -> Reduce Transparency and Reduce Motion.